# Why this shiny application is not working?

Tags: r

```
    library(leaflet)
    ui = fluidPage(

      TitlePannel
      titlePanel("Project Test"),

      SideBarLayout being used.
      sidebarLayout(
        #sidebar contains
        sidebarPanel(
                      textInput('log','EnterLongitude'), 
                      textInput(inputId = 'lati', label = 'EnterLatitude'),
                      actionButton("submit", "Submit")
                    ),# end of the sidebarPanel 

        #display contains                        
        mainPanel(renderLeaflet("info"))  #end of the mainPanel 
#i believe there might be some mistake in mainPanel
                   ) #end of the sidebar layout
          )# end of the fluid page layout

    #Start of the control function
    server = function(session, input, output){
       observeEvent(input$submit, {
        log <- as.numeric(input$log)
        lati <- as.numeric(input$lati)
        m = leaflet() %>% 
          addTiles() %>%
          addMarkers(lng = log, lat = lati , popup = "test",label = "a")
       }
      )

      selectedData <- reactive({
        m
      })

      output$info <- renderPrint({
        selectedData()
      })     
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)

Comment: The main panel should have plotted with the leaflet map
```

i am trying to plot the co-ordinate in the map as per the user enter the two text fields , i.e. longitude and latitude

Since, me novice to R-programming. Hope to get positive response. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to comment (#) your titlepanel and SideBarLayout sections.  You have left them and they run as a part of your code.

Comment: okay so i got the app to render but the plot didn't show up when I hit submit. Did you at least get your app to render? Can you also give an example of latitude and logitude to test this?

Comment: Test cases :  <longitude>88.15649050306635</longitude>
    <latitude>26.64607202682717</latitude>    || Map is not rendering as well .